# Include an association with condition rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a model *Books* with 2 associations say, *names* and *name*(has a condition along).

```
 class Book
   has_one :name, :conditions => 'place = "Bangalore"', :order => 'id DESC'
   has_many :names, :order => 'id DESC'
 end
```

So basically, *name* gives the latest name that was updates on a book and *names* will be the list of all names ever assigned to the book.

And Im using paginate gem to paginate the results.

```
@result.paginate(:select => "books.*", :include => :book)
```

But the above query includes all books and not the last one(i.e, book). Is there any way to specify include with a condition in **Rails 2.3** ? I tried this, but in vain.

```
 @result.paginate(:select => "books.*", :include => :book,:joins => :book, :conditions => 'books.palce="Bangalore"', :order => 'books.id DESC', :limit => 1)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes my suggestion would be to drop `:name` altogether and just use the latest entry in `:names` to signify the latest name.

Comment: rails 2.3 you can try named scope with a condition and then `@result.scope_name.paginate`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
class Book
  named_scope :bangalore, :conditions => 'place = "Bangalore"' 
end
```

Then

```
@result.bangalore.paginate(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
@result.joins(:book).includes(:book).paginate(..)
```